# What is the difference between Java EE and J2EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What is the difference between Java EE and J2EE. J2EE is a platform or framework?.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Definitely not. That one is about SE vs EE.

Comment: Java 2 was a name bandied around by Sun for a while during the Microsoft lawsuit. I think they wanted to characterize it as a new product & hence not part of their agreement with MS.

Comment: @EJP Well, it also has something to do with Sun's weird numbering scheme.  As far as I know, they started referring to it as Java 2 when Java 1.2 came out... but it wasn't until Java 5 when they actually started calling the product by its sub-version number.  For that matter, even now Java 8's internal numbering is 1.8.

Comment: @Powerlord That's exactly what I'm referring to. No 'also ' about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java EE (Enterprise edition): Formerly known as J2EE . It includes Java Standard Edition plus most of the other Java technologies including JavaMail, Activation, JAXB (Java API for XML Binding), Servlets, JSF (Java Server Faces), JMS (Java Messaging Service), EJB (Enterprise Java Beans), and others

Answer (score 7):

No difference. J2EE was the old name, Java EE is the current name. And it's a set of specifications, many frameworks (and platforms) implement some (or all) of said specifications.